# Undefined index: image and getimagesize: Read error! in php

Tags: php

This is my code for uploading images to database.

**index.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>upload images to database</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
File:
<input type= "file" name= "image">
<input type= "submit" value= "upload">
</form>
<?php
//connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("image") or die(mysql_error());
$file = '';
 $file= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 if(!isset($file))
 {
 echo "please select an image";
 }
 else
 {
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
if($image_size ==FALSE)
{
echo "That's not an image";
}
else
    {
    if(!$insert = "INSERT INTO upload VALUES('','$image_name','$image')")
    {
    echo "Problem uploading image";
    }
    else{

    $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
    echo "Image upload.<p/>Your Image</p><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";

    }
} 
 }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**get.php:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("image") or die(mysql_error());
$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];
header("content-type: image/ipeg");
echo $image;
?>
```

when will i run this code it shows like https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v3OV.jpg and before upload images it displayed Undefined index: image...

Can anyone help to fix my issues?

Thanks!!!

Comment: For one thing, it's `INSERT` not `INESRT`. If that's a typo in your code, change it in your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yes, i changed.. sorry for bad english.

Comment: You're not checking whether the form's been submitted; you're not checking `$_FILES['image']['error']` for any error status; you have typos in your query and mimetype header; `addslashes()` is not the way to escape input for SQL and you're using a deprecated interface (`mysql_*()`). There might be other problems.

Comment: @MikeW: Can you edit my code please, how to check $_FILES['image']['error']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test whether the script is being run when the form was just being displayed initially or when it was submitted:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    ... all the code that processes the form
}
?>
```

Also, you need to escape user input when inserting it into a query:

```
$image = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

This is especially important for `$image`, since it's binary data.

You're missing the call to `mysql_query()` to execute the `INSERT`. It should be:

```
if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload VALUES('','$image_name','$image')"))
{
    echo "Problem uploading image: ".mysql_error();
}
else{

    $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
    echo "Image upload.<p/>Your Image</p><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";

}
```

It would be better if you switched to PDO or mysqli extensions, and use prepared queries. The mysql extension is deprecated.

Comment: Please don't remove the original question. If you want to post new code for us to review, append it to the question. People who read the question have to be able to see what we fixed.

Comment: I already answered that. If you escape the data properly, I think the `INSERT` will work.

Comment: You're never calling `mysql_query` on the `INSERT` query!

Comment: Because `Save As` gets the default filename from the URL in the link, and the URL of your image is `get.php?id=XXX`.

Comment: You could use a rewrite rule on your server to rewrite something like `/images/image_XXX.jpg` to `get.php?id=XXX`. Then use the first URL in the link.

Comment: No, sorry, I can't. I don't really know much about configuring Apache rewrite rules.

Comment: I don't know how to answer such a vague question. I think you really need to learn how to code, you can't do it by asking questions here for every little detail. Please stop bothering me with this, I think you're too inexperienced for me to deal with.

Comment: There's a difference between inexperiences and doesn't know what he's doing at all.